# How to provide hardcoded file to this function?

Tags: python

I am trying to hard code file paths to a function that accepts filename as an argument in the code below:

```
def do_powershell( self, line ) :

    if not line :
        # usage
        return
    toks = line.split()
    filename = toks[0]
    stream_name = ''.join(filename.split('/')[-1].split('.')[:-1])  # for /tmp/great.shell.stage.py : great.shell.stage
    # try :
    try :
        stage_mod = imp.load_source('stage', filename)
        stage_dict = import_stage_from_module( stage_mod )
        self.__remoteLoadModule( stream_name, stage_dict )
        self.__localLoadModule( stream_name, stage_dict )
    except Exception as e:
        print( "File '%s' could not be loaded!" %  filename )
        traceback.print_exc()
        print( e )
        return

    return
```

Comment: are you saying that you want to pass a path into `do_powershell` using the `line` argument?

Comment: How is your file "hardcoded", is something preventing you from `filename = "/path/to/my/beloved/file"`?

Comment: I suggest you do all path manipulations using [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) functions (like `os.path.split()`) — although that apparently has nothing to do with what you're asking...

Comment: @dedObed That was my idea as well and it worked, thanks for all your contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking for this?

```
def do_powershell( self, line, path='/some/path' ) :
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, solution below worked for me pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Case closed.

```
def do_powershell( self, line ) :

    #if not line :
        # usage
    #   return
    #toks = line.split()
    filename = '/file/path/filename.py'
    stream_name = 'powershell'  # for /tmp/great.shell.stage.py : great.shell.stage
    # try :
    try :
        stage_mod = imp.load_source('stage', filename)
        stage_dict = import_stage_from_module( stage_mod )
        self.__remoteLoadModule( stream_name, stage_dict )
        self.__localLoadModule( stream_name, stage_dict )
    except Exception as e:
        print( "File '%s' could not be loaded!" %  filename )
        traceback.print_exc()
        print( e )
        return

    return
```